# Eclipse e4 application: parts opened by default for the first run

Tags: eclipse, rcp, e4

I have an eclipse e4 application, with a main plugin with an "Application.e4xmi" describing a view with some part stacks.

Also, I have a fragment plugin with a "fragment.e4xmi" contributing some things.

If the fragment plugin contributes with a part, the part is opened for the first time the application is executed, but if I move it to another part stack, and open the part with a button handler (using the EPartService), it will be opened again (I don't understand why).

If the fragment plugin contributes with a part descriptor, the part is opened only once using the handler, but for the first application run time, the part is not created (and I need it).

What is the correct way to create a part/part descriptor in a fragment plugin and get it opened **only** for the application first execution (if the user closes the part, it should remain closed for the next application execution).

Comment: I found a related post in the eclipse forums, but not sure about how to solve it: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1087254/

Comment: Are you specifying the '-clearPersistedState' or '-persistState false' options on the run?

Comment: @greg-449 No, I'm not using it, because I need to mantain the model state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found, the best way to do it is adding **apply="initial"** to the fragment tag in the plugin.xml file. It works as expected.

You can see more info at:
https://help.eclipse.org/photon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_e4_workbench_model.html